# Replace an integer within an attribute with +1

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'd like to add a new nested element to a given Rails 4 form.

CoffeeScript:

```
ready = ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_comment', (event) ->
    new_fields = $(this).parent().prev('div.field').clone()
    new_fields.insertBefore('p.new_comment_link')
    event.preventDefault()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Before I do the `insertBefore` I'd like to change some attributes within `new_fields`. The content of `new_fields` is:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="post_comments_attributes_2_name">Name</label><br>
  <input id="post_comments_attributes_2_name" name="post[comments_attributes][2][name]" type="text">
  <input id="post_comments_attributes_2__destroy" name="post[comments_attributes][2][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false">
  <a class="remove_category" href="#">remove</a>
</div>
```

How can I replace all `[2]` with +1 (`[3]`) without knowing that [2] is a 2? It could be any integer.

Comment: A little OT, but have you considered using ``data`` attributes on the parent field? [Link](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). That way you could clone the element and only manipulate an ``attr`` once, without the need for multiple regexes.

Comment: How could I solve the problem by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you don't only need to modify the name of the inputs, but you also need to modify the labels and ids, this is to prevent any sort of malfunctions that depend on the taxonomy of those attributes.

The CoffeeScript looks like this:

```
String.prototype.parseIntPlusOne = ->
  this.replace /(\d+)/, (match, num)->
    parseInt(num, 10) + 1

ready = ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_comment', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    new_field = $(this).parent().prev('div.field').clone()

    new_field.find('label').attr 'for', (i, attr)->
      attr.parseIntPlusOne()

    new_field.find('input').attr('id', (i, attr)->
      attr.parseIntPlusOne()).attr('name', (i, attr)->
      attr.parseIntPlusOne())

    new_field.insertBefore('p.new_comment_link')

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

And you can view a working example here: http://codepen.io/MarioRicalde/pen/AFLIe

Comment: -1: Why would you modify the prototype of `String` to add such a specific function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()` with a callback function:

```
'[1] [2]'.replace /\[(\d+)\]/g, (match, num) ->
    return "[#{parseInt(num, 10) + 1}]"
```

And the JavaScript equivalent:

```
'[1] [2]'.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function(match, num) {
    return '[' + (parseInt(num, 10) + 1) + ']';
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the # do inside that string?

Comment: @JuanMendes: String interpolation. It's a nicer way of writing that JavaScript code below the CoffeeScript.

Comment: I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'` error when I use this. I tried: `new_fields = $(this).parent().prev('div.field').clone().replace /\[(\d+)\]/g, (match, num) ->
      return "[#{parseInt(num, 10) + 1}]"`

Comment: @wintermeyer: You can't call `.replace()` on a jQuery object. If you want to replace its text, use `.text()`.

Comment: @Blender: How can I insert it later when I use `.text()` first? I can't get the code running in the given example.

Comment: @wintermeyer: `.text()` returns the text of the element. You can set the element's text by passing a string into `.text()`.

Comment: @Blender: How can I combine all this to do the wanted replacement within `new_fields`?